# How to split column header in Pandas and export to Excel properly

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have following data header in Pandas:

[image]

and I am struggling to get below result:

[image]

I was trying to perform a command:

```
df = df.reorder_levels([0, 1, 3, 2], axis='columns')
```

However it's just reorder the rows, and I see risks here to break data consistency.

May you advise pandas/pythonic way to do it? Or what options should I check to export to Excel properly (as image 2)?

Comment: I think it is only default visualization of MultiIndex - check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object), find`In [20]: pd.set_option('display.multi_sparse', False)`

Comment: Yes, it works for visualization in Jupyter, however when you export to Excel the problem still same. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into this problem and found another dirty, but easier hack.

As long as the first header row has different values, df.to_excel will save the subsequent rows of headers as separate values. So when setting your headers, make the first row unique characters and disregard it in the rest of your code.

Without unique first header row:

```
df1 =  pd.DataFrame(columns=[['APPROACH #1', 'APPROACH #1', 'APPROACH #1', 'APPROACH #1', 'APPROACH #1'],
                         ['CODE', 'CODE', 'CODE', 'CODE', 'CODE'],
                         ['GLMNET', 'HYBER', 'LightGBM', 'XGB_1', 'XGB_2']])
```

[Image of df1 result with merged header values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAcnQ.png)

With unique first header row:

```
df2 =  pd.DataFrame(columns=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                         ['APPROACH #1', 'APPROACH #1', 'APPROACH #1', 'APPROACH #1', 'APPROACH #1'],
                         ['CODE', 'CODE', 'CODE', 'CODE', 'CODE'],
                         ['GLMNET', 'HYBER', 'LightGBM', 'XGB_1', 'XGB_2']])
```

[Image of df2 result with separate header values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Kwp.png)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use only some hack solutions - create helper `df` from `MultiIndex` in columns and then write to `excel` without header:

```
np.random.seed(100)
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('ABC'), list('EF')])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1,6)), columns=cols)
print (df)
          A                   B                   C          
          E         F         E         F         E         F
0  0.543405  0.278369  0.424518  0.844776  0.004719  0.121569

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.columns.values.tolist()).T
df1.columns.name = None
df1.index = [''] * len(df1.index)
print (df1)
  0  1  2  3  4  5
  A  A  B  B  C  C
  E  F  E  F  E  F

df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
df = pd.concat([df1, df])
print (df)
          0         1         2         3           4         5
          A         A         B         B           C         C
          E         F         E         F           E         F
0  0.543405  0.278369  0.424518  0.844776  0.00471886  0.121569

df.to_excel('myfile.xlsx', header=None)
```

Another solution with double transpose:

```
df1 = df.T.rename_axis(['',' ']).reset_index().T
print (df1)
          0         1         2         3           4         5
          A         A         B         B           C         C
          E         F         E         F           E         F
0  0.543405  0.278369  0.424518  0.844776  0.00471886  0.121569

df.to_excel('myfile.xlsx', header=None)
```